# jQuery live not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Why below code does not work:

```
$('button[name="publish"]', 'button[name="cancel"]').live('click', function(){
    alert('ddddd');
});
```

The html is generated dynamically which is basically facebook's Share dialog which has these two buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="publish" value="Share">
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
```

- Reference to jQuery lib is fine and checked
- Using ready handler

---

The page can be viewed here:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Development-Application-Testing-Page/124719744278421?sk=app_126015774115928

Comment: Replace `', '` with `,`.

Comment: You shouldn't use live. You should use `delegate()` pre 1.7 and `on()` 1.7 and above. :) `live()` has been depreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current selector is [short](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) for:

```
$('button[name="cancel"]').find('button[name="publish"]')
```

That's not intended. You're looking for:

```
$('button[name="publish"], button[name="cancel"]')
```

Comment: event not triggered still: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Development-Application-Testing-Page/124719744278421?sk=app_126015774115928

Comment: @Dev555 I tried hard, but I cannot find these buttons at your page. Can you post a stand-alome demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: The feed with buttons should appeaer when you click Unlock to Download blue button below image. Thanks

Comment: @Dev555 Still not visible. FYI, I am not authenticated when visiting your FB page. If you want more help, create a standalone demo.

Answer (score 2):

Because your selector is slightly wrong. Try this (note the fact that the entire selector expression is quoted):

```
$('button[name="publish"], button[name="cancel"]').live('click', function(){
    alert('ddddd');
});
```

What you currently have is looking for the first part of the selector (`button[name="publish"]`) and using the second part of the selector as a context (in other words, it looks for elements that match `button[name="publish"]` and are descendants of elements matching `button[name="cancel"]`).

Also note that the `live` method is deprecated. If you're using jQuery 1.7+ use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you're using an older version then use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: event not triggered still: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Development-Application-Testing-Page/124719744278421?sk=app_126015774115928

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because your are trying to select an "input" with a $('button...')

try this

```
$('input[name="publish"] , input[name="cancel"]').live('click', function(){
    alert('ddddd');
});
```

Comment: +1 for the notion of the `button` selector. The "fixed" code contains a flaw though. Replace `', '` with `'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=publish] , input[name=cancel]').live('click', function(){
    alert('ddddd');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button[name="publish"], button[name="cancel"]').live('click', function(){
    alert('ddddd');
});
```